# imagemagick commandline resize to fixed width/height keeping scale

Tags: command-line, images, imagemagick

I am currently using PHP, but its resampling is not good enough for my needs.

Suppose I have an image 200x200. I need it resize to 100x50. Then I need it resized scaled down cleanly as possible (here 50x50) but centered in the 100x50 image (with a background/transparent color filling left/right padding)

I have this working in PHP. But again, results not good enough.

I have trouble identifying the necessary command line instructions for this... I can pass all x/y/width/height if that helps instructing imagemagick.

Answer (score 1):

With imagemagick you can do this:

```
convert <input_filename> -resize '100x50>' -background '#ffffff00' -gravity center -extent 100x50 <output_filename>
```

Explanation:

- `-resize '100x50>` resizes to fit in a 100x50 box keeping the aspect ratio. `>` means that it will never enlarge the input image, e.g. if input is 40x20 it will keep it like that.
- `-background '#ffffff00'` sets the background color for any padding that will be necessary. In this case it is a fully transparent (the alpha value `00`), but you can use any color of course. Transparent will only work, if your output file type supports transparency.
- `-gravity center` means to center the scaled image to the padded image.
- `-extent 100x50` means to pad the scaled image to fill up the 100x50 box by the given background color.

Comment: Thank you. I will test soon and get back. I want it to resize optimally using as much of the image as possible (but keeping aspects and not cropping anything) -- and then fill/pad where needed using background color to fit the new image size.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what the command should be doing if I understand you correctly. One thing that is a little ambiguous is what you want to happen if the original image is smaller than 100x50. In my answer, small images are just being padded in all directions with the background to fill up the 100x50 rectangle, without enlarging the actual image. If you want small images to be also enlarged, you just need to replace `-resize '100x50>'` with `-resize '100x50'` (without the `>`!).